# What is the policy of Stack Overflow in face of the question that has already been asked before?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, policy

What is the policy of Stack Overflow in face of the question that has already been asked before?

Because that question might have been asked a long time before and how does this site manage redundant questions?

Answer (score 2):

Users with more than 3000 reputation can vote to close. One of the options is "duplicate" and selected that presents a dialog into which you enter the duplicate question id.

Subsequent closers see this question and can either pick it or select their own example - if there's more than one duplicate.

That said, duplicate questions can be a good thing - as long as they all point to the same set of answers. If there's several ways of asking the same question having them all represented means that at least one of them is more likely to be found when someone looks for the question in the future.

So look for your question, ask it if you can't find it, but don't be surprised or upset if it gets closed.

One last point, questions can be reopened, so if you think it was closed unfairly ask a question here - with a link to the question - giving your reasons why you don't think your question is really a duplicate.

Comment: Unfortunately many people - especially here on meta - give a hard time if someone asks a question that has been asked before, even with a different wording. =o

Comment: @Kop - true, but if you look and *read* the suggestions you get after entering your title then there's less chance of it happening.